# How to handle onTap on audio notif with plugin audio_service flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio, background-process, just-audio, audio-service

I want to handle notification on tap when app in foreground or background then redirect to specific page, I use [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) plugin to handle background audio, can [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to notification click events via one of the following streams:

- (v0.17): `AudioService.notificationClickEventStream`
- (v0.18): `AudioService.notificationClicked`

For example:

```dart
AudioService.notificationClicked.listen((clicked) {
  if (clicked) {
    // Navigate to the right page based on your app's state
  }
});
```

Comment: I've used `AudioService.notificationClickEventStream` in version (v0.17). The stream click listen when app on background only, if click notif when app on foreground the stream always listen false. @ryanheise

Comment: actually solved with version (v0.18). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I define the stream in main() :

```
  AudioService.notificationClicked.listen((event) {
    print('--- Cliked ---');
    _navigationService.push(routes: Routes.PLAYER_PAGE);
  });
```

I used dependency injection for navigation service which it can push to another page without context [@BalasubramanianS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15991981/balasubramanian-s)